# I need to create a n-dimensional point with coordinates. The Constructor should take any number of coordinates.

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, constructor, n-dimensional

There is alot more in this project but I dont know how to start Im stuck on how to create a constructor with an array that will take a unknown number of dimensions in a point.

Comment: why you can't use an array as argument?

Comment: I dont know how to structure the constructor to take a unknown dimensional number in a point. The last project we did we had to get the linelenght of 3D coordinate x,y,z. But in this project we have to use n-dimensional which it could be x,y,z,a,b,c.... until user presses Exit. Then I need to get the linelenght from the dimensions from the two points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an array as an argument for your constructor

```
public class MultiDemPoint{
    public MultiDemPoint(double[] coords){

    }
}
```

You will need to pass an array of doubles:

`new MultiDemPoint(new double[]{4, 5.0, 3, 2, 6, 4.6});`

---

You can also expect undefined number of coordinates as separated values

```
public class MultiDemPoint{
    public MultiDemPoint(double... coords){

    }
}
```

You can pass parametrs like `new MultiDemPoint(4, 5.0, 3, 2, 6, 4.6);` in this case.

---

Practice:

- Create a new empty project in your IDE
- Create  `MultDemPoint.java` file with following code:

  ```
  public class MultiDemPoint{
      private double[] coords;
      //double... coords will automatically convert all supplied coordinates to the array,
      // we can store it in double[] coords.
      public MultiDemPoint(double... coords){
          this.coords = coords;
      }

      public void printCoords(){
          for(int i=0; i<coords.length; i++){
              System.out.println("Coordinate #"+i+": "+coords[i]);
          }
          System.out.println("");
      }
  }
  ```
- Use this code for your `Main.java`

  ```
  public class Main {
          public static void main(String[] args){
          MultiDemPoint point1 = new MultiDemPoint(1,2,3,4);
          MultiDemPoint point2 = new MultiDemPoint(3);
          MultiDemPoint point3 = new MultiDemPoint(5.44444444,232323.12323,321321);
          System.out.println("Point1 coordinates:");
          point1.printCoords();

          System.out.println("Point2 coordinates:");
          point2.printCoords();

          System.out.println("Point3 coordinates:");
          point3.printCoords();

      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Inside the method block you would treat the varargs argument as an array, so the first `double` would be `coords[0]` exactly as in his first example. It just allows for more convenient invocation of the method... you get to do `MultiDemPoint(1,4,8,9)` instead of `double[] d = {1, 4, 8, 9}; MultiDemPoint(d)`.

Comment: @user3023185 check updates

Comment: Any suggestions of What should I use for the getters and setters in the constructor. I the last project I was using x and y. But in this project is undefined.

Comment: @user3023185 for now, there is only private field `coords` of type `double` without getter. But you can add `public double[] getCoords(){ return coords }` and use it to obtain the list of coordinates that you specified on creation. You need to read more about programming to make it clear. https://www.udacity.com/course/cs046 is a great place to start if you're unfamiliar with java and programming in general, Oracle also has a great documentation-like tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass an array, you can use so called "varargs".

```
public class Point
{
 public Point(double... x)
 {
 }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
new Point(1, 2, 3);
new Point(1, 2, 3, 4);
```